# changing the frequency of loop

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

following is the snipet of my code i want to change the frequency with which the image is pubished i tried changing the loop_rate(10) to loop_rate(1) but it didn't work

```
    ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
    int counter =0;
       while(ros::ok() ){
    counter++;
        #if 1
            ros::Time time = ros::Time::now();
            cv_ptr->encoding = "bgr8";
            cv_ptr->header.stamp = time;
            
cv_ptr->header.frame_id = "/Sufyan_ImageTopic";
        #endif

            cv_ptr->image = image;
            image_pub_.publish(cv_ptr->toImageMsg());

            ROS_INFO("ImageMsg Send.");
        #endif
        
        }   
    
    ros::spin();
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304027/changing-the-frequency-of-loop/) by [Sufyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/36896/sufyan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2018-09-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
you must to use loop_rate.sleep() in the end of while to control your loop rate

```
           while(ros::ok() ){
               counter++;
#if 1
                ros::Time time = ros::Time::now();
                cv_ptr->encoding = "bgr8";
                cv_ptr->header.stamp = time;
    
               cv_ptr->header.frame_id = "/Sufyan_ImageTopic";
 #endif
    
                cv_ptr->image = image;
                image_pub_.publish(cv_ptr->toImageMsg());
    
                ROS_INFO("ImageMsg Send.");
#endif
                loop_rate.sleep();
            }
```

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2018-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2